# Hide parent div if list is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following....

```
<div class="validationbox">
    <h1>Errors</h1>
        <ul class="validationerrors">
            <li>Error 1</li>
            <li>Error 2</li>
            <li>Error 3</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The error list items are generated dynamically so sometimes there are none,  I would like to hide the 'validationbox' div if there are no list items.

I imagine it is javascript or jquery that I should be looking at, does anyone have any examples?

Comment: if($("#validationerrors").length>1){}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In jQuery you can do it as simple as:

```
$(".validationbox:not(:has(li))").hide();
```

In pure JavaScript you need to iterate ".validationbox" elements and search for `<li>` nodes inside:

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("validationbox");
for (var i = 0, len = div.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (!div[i].getElementsByTagName("li").length) {
        div[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer, if it works for you, and it will help the others.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.validationbox').toggle( $('.validationerrors li').length );
```

`toggle()` accepts a boolean value as an argument. `$('.validationerrors li').length` will evaluate to false if there is no `<li>` elements, else true, which will show the error list.

Answer (score 1):

you can use not .

```
$('div .validationbox').not(':has(li)').hide();
```

hope it's help to you